# For Apache NetBeans IDE 11.2, how do I point it to the correct version of JDK on my Fedora Linux System?

Tags: java, linux, netbeans

In NetBeans, I'm getting the error: Additional modules are needed to run Java SE support on JDK 8. How do I point Netbeans 11 to the correct version of JDK 8? I know where it is on my Fedora system, I just don't know how to tell Netbeans where it is. I'm on a standalone system, not connected to the internet. As a result, I'm unable to click the "Download and Activate" button, and for some reason the "Activate" button next to it is grayed out. I am unable to download the NetBeans IDE Plugin installer.

Under the Options >> Nashorn tab, I see that there is a way to import a path to JDK 8, but when I attempt to select it, then I get the following error: "Folder does not seem to be a valid userdir. Importing options from this location cannot proceed."

Comment: You can specify it on the command line when starting netbeans using `--jdkhome /path/to/jdk`

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name:  That didn't work. I get the following error: "bash: --jdkhome: command not found."  Do I need an environment variable instead, like "export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jdk"? Am I supposed to do this all in my bash shell/terminal?

Comment: No, it's a **parameter** for the NetBeans binary when you start it. http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqJdkHome

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: please update this as the answer to my question.

Comment: @macdays Please post an answer to your own question, and then accept it. That will be more helpful to community.

Comment: This link (from a_horse_with_no_name) is the answer my original question. http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqJdkHome

Comment: @skomisa I posted the answer above, but how to I accept it? I only have 13 points, I think I may need the minimum 15 points.